# Error when attempting to submit form with Rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Adapting [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146723/rvest-unknown-field-names-when-attempting-to-set-form), I'm trying to use `rvest` to generate a form to scrape the resulting page. I keep coming up with an error.

```
library(rvest)


url <- "https://iemweb.biz.uiowa.edu/pricehistory/pricehistory_SelectContract.cfm?market_ID=214"

pg.session <- html_session(url)

pg.form <- html_form(html(pg.session))

filled_form <- set_values(pg.form[[1]],
                      Month = "8",
                      Year = "1")

out <- submit_form(session = pg.session, pg.form)
```

returns this error

```
Submitting with ''
Error in if (!(submit %in% names(submits))) { : 
 argument is of length zero
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for one thing, you are not submitting the form you actually filled in and you are also attempting to pass in a list of forms rather than a form, but also it appears there may be a bug in the code that doesn't recognize submit buttons with upper case tags. In this case, the HTML has the code

```
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Get Prices">
```

and the `submit_form` codes calls `submit_request` which looks for submit buttons via

```
submits <- Filter(function(x) identical(x$type, "submit"), 
    form$fields)
```

and since it checks for values identical to "submit" it's not finding "SUBMIT"

```
sapply(pg.form[[1]]$fields, function(x) x$type)
# $Market_ID
# [1] "HIDDEN"
# $Month
# NULL
# $Year
# NULL
# $`NULL`
# [1] "SUBMIT"
```

The easiest thing might be to change it ourselves

```
filled_form <- set_values(pg.form[[1]],
                      Month = "08",
                      Year = "2007")
filled_form$fields[[4]]$type <- "submit"
```

The other problem is that this version has a bug in the way the URL for the form us resolved. we can fix it with

```
# incorrectly was: url <- XML::getRelativeURL(session$url, form$url)
body(submit_form)[[3]]<-quote(url <- XML::getRelativeURL(form$url, session$url))
```

And now finally we can submit the request

```
out <- submit_form(session = pg.session, filled_form)
# out %>% html_table()
```

(Tested with rvest_0.2.0.9000)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this! one final question-- when I run

     out %>% html_table()

i'm not returned the actual price data. How do I access the underlying price table?

Comment: @tomw There was an existing bug in how the URL of the form was resolved. I've posted a work-around. I know that error has been patched in the github version. not sure about the "SUMBIT" one.